# "Money transfer" or "Wire transfer"

Tags: idioms

Which one is more correct?

> Money transfer

or

> Wire transfer

---

**EDIT:** the context is the typical web form where a user can choose the type of payment. "Credit card", rather than "Paypal", rather than "Money/Wire transfer".

In Italian there is a specific name for such type of transaction (the Money/Wire transfer, this is the reason why I'm asking).

Comment: Specify a context.  Otherwise, question is not constructive, not a real question, too localized, or general reference.

Comment: @jwpat7- I think OP is just asking about the difference between the two, as it could be interchangeable in some cases.

Comment: Both are correct but it depends on how do you want to use it.

Comment: @jwpat7: I updated the question.

Comment: Why -1? What's wrong wth this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wire transfer is mostly a US usage, money transfer is probably more universal.

If you are using this in a technical context, software or a report, then EFT (Electronic Funds Transfer) is probably the more correct phrase.

Answer (score 1):

They're... equally correct depending as jwpat7 says on the context.  *Money transfer* refers to that which is being transferred.  *Wire transfer* puts focus on the conveyance itself.